# How to get an average of the same ID and post/show it to other table in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two eloquent table, which is the Penyedia's table and Pekerjaan's table. **Penyedia hasMany Pekerjaans and Pekerjaan belongsTo Penyedia**. Inside the table there are foreign key which is the 'penyedia_id' and the 'nilai_total' (total score). Here is the picture of my Pekerjaan's Table:
[image: Pekerjaan's table]

I want to get the average of the total score with the same 'penyedia_id' (like the picture below) and pass/post and show it to the Penyedia's Table. How can I do that in actual view in Laravel?
[image: Avg with the same penyedia_id]

Here is my code in AdminController:

```
public function tabelnilai_penyedia(){
        $penyedia = Penyedia::all();
        $pekerjaan = Pekerjaan::all();

        //$totalAvg=$penyedia->pekerjaans()->avg('nilai_total');
        $totalAvg = Pekerjaan::selectRaw("penyedia_id, AVG(nilai_total) AS avg")->groupBy('penyedia_id')->get();

        return view('admin.datanilai_penyedia', compact('penyedia', 'pekerjaan','totalAvg'));
    }
```

Here is the blade file for the table view:

```
<section class="content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                  <h3 class="card-title">Tabel Penilaian Penyedia</h3>
                  
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-header -->
                <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                  <table id="tabelpenyedia" class="table table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th style="width: 10px">No.</th>
                        <th>Nama Penyedia</th>
                        <th>Nilai</th>
                        <th style="width: 120px">Aksi</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      @php $no = 1; @endphp
                      @foreach ($penyedia as $penyedias)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{$no++}}</td>
                        <td>{{$penyedias->nama}}</td>
                        <td>{{$totalAvg}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="/nilaipekerjaan/{{$penyedias->id}}" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outline-primary">Detail</a>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
              </div>
              <!-- /.card -->
  
            
    </div>
</section>
```

Here what the table is looks like atm:
[image]

Thank you.

Edit: updated code and view

Comment: You don't need this `@php $no = 1; @endphp` use `<td>{{ $penyedias->iteration }}</td>` instead. Check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: Use `Penyedia::selectRaw("*, AVG(nelai_total) AS avg")->groupBy('penyedia_id')->get()`

Comment: And how should I call it to the table? After using the query above in the admincontroller? Thank in advance @Kerkouch

Comment: I've found this error >SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'webpenyedia.pekerjaans.id' isn't in GROUP BY